# how to translate the SQL code "having" condition into LinqToSQL or LinqToEntites?

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, having

Could you tell me how to translate the following SQL code to Linq To SQL or Linq To Entites?

The correct SQL code is:

> select CollectId,url,userid,pubtime
>   from Collect group by
>   url,collectid,userid,pubtime  having
>   pubtime >= (select max(pubtime) from
>   collect d where d.url = collect.url  )
>   order by Collect.pubtime desc

The database table script is:

> if exists (select * from sysobjects
>   where id = OBJECT_ID('[Collect]') and
>   OBJECTPROPERTY(id, 'IsUserTable') = 1)
>   DROP TABLE [Collect]
>
> CREATE TABLE [Collect] ( [CollectId]
>   [int]  IDENTITY (1, 1)  NOT NULL,
>   [Url] [nvarchar]  (200) NULL, [UserId]
>   [nvarchar]  (50) NULL, [PubTime]
>   [datetime]  NULL)
>
> ALTER TABLE [Collect] WITH NOCHECK ADD
>   CONSTRAINT [PK_Collect] PRIMARY KEY 
>   NONCLUSTERED ( [CollectId] ) SET
>   IDENTITY_INSERT [Collect] ON
>
> INSERT [Collect]
>   ([CollectId],[Url],[UserId],[PubTime])
>   VALUES (
>   1,'www.sohu.com','Mike','2008-10-10
>   0:00:00') INSERT [Collect]
>   ([CollectId],[Url],[UserId],[PubTime])
>   VALUES (
>   2,'www.echina365.com','Lily','2008-10-15
>   0:00:00') INSERT [Collect]
>   ([CollectId],[Url],[UserId],[PubTime])
>   VALUES (
>   3,'www.php.com','Tom','2008-10-20
>   0:00:00') INSERT [Collect]
>   ([CollectId],[Url],[UserId],[PubTime])
>   VALUES (
>   4,'www.echina365.com','YaoMing','2008-10-23
>   0:00:00') INSERT [Collect]
>   ([CollectId],[Url],[UserId],[PubTime])
>   VALUES (
>   5,'www.echina365.com','Mike','2008-10-25
>   0:00:00') INSERT [Collect]
>   ([CollectId],[Url],[UserId],[PubTime])
>   VALUES (
>   6,'www.sohu.com','Jack','2008-10-26
>   0:00:00') INSERT [Collect]
>   ([CollectId],[Url],[UserId],[PubTime])
>   VALUES (
>   7,'www.echina365.com','Tracy','2008-11-2
>   0:00:00') INSERT [Collect]
>   ([CollectId],[Url],[UserId],[PubTime])
>   VALUES (
>   8,'www.php.com','YaoMing','2008-11-5
>   0:00:00')
>
> SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Collect] OFF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your "having" condition isn't actually on an aggregated column, couldn't you just use the "where" clause?

```
select distinct CollectId, url, userid, pubtime
from Collect
where pubtime >= (select max(pubtime) from collect d where d.url = collect.url)
order by Collect.pubtime desc
```

This gets the same result given the dataset you've supplied. The LINQ statement then becomes reasonably simple:

```
var rows = (from c in Collect
where c.PubTime >= (
    from d in Collect
    where d.Url == c.Url
    select d.PubTime).Max()
orderby c.PubTime descending
select c).Distinct();
```

I could be misinterpreting your intent though. Perhaps my version of the query doesn't do exactly what you want. If so, leave me a comment and I'll delete the answer so as not to confuse the issue.